# How to Add value from database into <a>

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing a url into mysql database. Now i want to display on front end, so when user clicks on read more button, it should take to the URL which is stored in database. 
Current code is

```
<?php
                        $SelectMainCats = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cms_service LIMIT 0, 1");
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($SelectMainCats)){

                        $a1heading          = $row['a1heading'];
                        $rm1_link           = $row['rm1_link'];
?>
```

HTML of this

```
<a href="<?php echo($rm1_link);?>" class="custom-btn mr-3 mt-3"> <i class="fas fa-plus f-14 mr-3 "></i> Ver más</a>
```

Suggestions  please
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that you were not including the html anchor tag inside your while loop so that's why you were not getting any url's on your web page. Here's the demo code for you.

```
<?php
        $SelectMainCats = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cms_service LIMIT 0, 1");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($SelectMainCats)){
              $a1heading          = $row['a1heading'];
              $rm1_link           = $row['rm1_link'];
           echo '<a href=". $rm1_link . " class="custom-btn mr-3 mt-3"><i class="fas fa-plus f-14 mr-3"></i> Ver mas</a>"';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: They have the `href` tag. All I see is that they left out the closing brace `}`.

Comment: thanks for the great answer. but in my HTML, there are difference sections where every section has different heading and links. so by your above code, it will not help me. For live example, here is the link of it
https://intellectsofts.com/demo/zinkla/service.html

i am doing PHP in my localhost.

Comment: there are 7 sections with different headings and links. i have shared the code for 1 link which i included in the while loop. if you say i can share full code

Comment: You'll have to save the url's with the section id inside your database and then call them section by section inside your website.

Comment: can you please look at the link and guide me more better and easy please.